# Outlook VBA Programming

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

Im trying to loop through attachments. IF format of any attachment is PDF or doc or docx then prompt vbYesNo

For some reason its not working :(

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Atmt As attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim vError As Variant
    Dim sErrors As String

    i = 0

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        Debug.Print Atmt.FileName

        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = "docx" Then

            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next Atmt

    If i > 0 Then

        strPrompt = "You have attached a document. Is this a CV Submission?"

        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Attachment") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = False

        Else:

              Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
              Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
              Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
              Dim sConnString As String

              ' Create the connection string.
              sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=WIN-NBST3PHVFV4\ECLIPSE;" & _
                            "Initial Catalog=OBlive;" & _
                            "User ID=outlook;Password=0Zzy007;"

              ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
             Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
             Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
             Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

             ' Open the connection and execute.
             conn.Open sConnString
             Set rs = conn.Execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Submissions (CV_Sent, Consultant, Timestamp) VALUES ( '1','" & myNamespace.CurrentUser & "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )")
             ' Clean up
             If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
             Set conn = Nothing
             Set rs = Nothing

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Im currently testing this with a docx attachment, Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your check is only looking for docx anyway and is case-sensitive. Try this:

```
If (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = UCase("docx")) Or _
   (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 3)) = UCase("pdf")) Or _
   (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 3)) = UCase("doc")) Then

        i = i + 1

End If
```

Comment: Thanks ive tried the code you have posted but its coming up with a syntax error

Comment: before the message box wasnt appearing but now with the UCase im getting compile error Syntax error and the ucase code is red